# Identical objects and identical boxes

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of ways of distributing 999 identical balls into 3 identical boxes.

This number(999) is too huge to allow a case by case treatment.

Ans: 83667

Comment: Note: stars and bars gives the answer for *non*-identical boxes.

Comment: @MeesdeVries thanks, deleted. Then we have a case of integer partition.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Break into 3 cases
1. all boxes have same num of balls
2. exactly 2 boxes have same num of balls
3. all boxes have different num of balls

Case 1 and 2  are trivial to solve
Case 3: solve assuming boxes are different (this is a std combinatorics problem) . reduce that by number where you could permute the distribution across boxes across all the cases (as boxes are identical)

finally add the 3 cases off course

Answer (score 2):

Let $n_1 \le n_2 \le n_3$ be the number of balls in the three boxes in sorted order. Since the balls and boxes are identical, the configuration is uniquely specified by the triple ($n_1,n_2,n_3$).

Let $m_1 = n_1$, $m_2 = n_2 - n_1$ and $m_3 = n_3 - n_2$. The condition $n_1 \le n_2 \le n_3$ becomes $m_1, m_2, m_3 \ge 0$. 
The problem at hand reduces to finding the number of solutions for

$$
\color{red}{3m_1} +
\color{green}{2m_2} +
\color{blue}{m_3} = n_1 + n_2 + n_3 = N\quad\quad\text{ for }\quad m_1,m_2,m_3 \in \mathbb{N}^3$$
when $N = 999$.

Let $p_N$ be the number of ways of putting $N$ identical balls into $3$ identical boxes.
Above discussion tells us the OGF of $p_N$ equals to

$$f(z) \stackrel{def}{=} \sum_{N=0}^\infty p_N z^N = \frac{1}{
\color{red}{(1-z^3)}
\color{green}{(1-z^2)}
\color{blue}{(1-z)}
}$$
With help of a CAS, we can partial fraction decompose RHS and get

$$\begin{align}
f(z) &= \frac16\frac{1}{(1-z)^3} + \frac14 \frac{1}{(1-z)^2} + \frac{17}{72}\frac{1}{1-z}
+ \frac18\frac{1}{1+z} + \frac19\frac{2+z}{1+z+z^2}\\
&= \frac16\frac{1}{(1-z)^3} + \frac14 \frac{1}{(1-z)^2} + \frac{17}{72}\frac{1}{1-z}
+ \frac18\frac{1-z}{1-z^2} + \frac19\frac{2-z-z^2}{1-z^3}
\end{align}
$$

Notice 
$$\begin{align}
\frac{1-z}{1-z^2} &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty d_k z^k\quad\text{ where }\quad d_k = \begin{cases}
+1, & k \equiv 0 \pmod 2\\
-1, & k \equiv 1 \pmod 2\\
\end{cases}\\
\frac{2-z-z^2}{1-z^3} &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty e_k z^k\quad\text{ where }\quad e_k = \begin{cases}
2,  & k \equiv 0 \pmod 2\\
-1, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$
Together with followings expansions for any $m \ge 1$,
$$\frac{1}{(1-z)^m} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{k+m-1}{m-1} z^k$$

We get

$$p_N = \frac16\binom{N+2}{2} + \frac14\binom{N+1}{1} + 
\frac{17}{72} + \frac18 d_N + \frac19 e_N
= \frac{(N+1)(N+5) + f_N}{12}
$$
where $\quad
f_N = 12\left(\frac{17}{72} + \frac18 d_N + \frac19 e_N\right) = \begin{cases}
7, & N \equiv 0 \pmod 6,\\
0, & N \equiv 1,5 \pmod 6\\
3, & N \equiv 2,4 \pmod 6\\
4, & N \equiv 3\pmod 6\\
\end{cases}$

Notice $0 \le \frac{f_N}{12} < 1$ and $p_N$ is an integer, we can simplify above
formula to

$$p_N = \left\lceil\frac{(N+1)(N+5)}{12}\right\rceil$$

Substitute $N = 999$ in this formula, the number of ways of placing $999$ identical balls into $3$ identical boxes equals to:

$$p_{999} = \left\lceil\frac{1000 \times 1004}{12}\right\rceil = 83667$$